# Add interactive Folium Background to osmnx maps

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx, traffic-simulation

I'm using osmnx map plots to find the shortest path and the 3 shortest paths between 2 points as in the below code:

```
location = (18.5204,73.8567)
mode = "drive"
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
G = ox.graph_from_point(location, dist=2000, simplify=True, network_type=mode)
nodes_proj, edges_proj = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=True)
ox.plot_graph(G,node_color='r')

origin_point = (18.515802, 73.846754)
destination_point =(18.519423, 73.852966)

origin_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, origin_point[1], origin_point[0])
print('origin_node',origin_node)

destination_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, destination_point[1], destination_point[0])
print('destination_node',destination_node)
bgcolor = "#061529"
route = ox.distance.shortest_path(G, origin_node,destination_node)
route
bbox = ox.utils_geo.bbox_from_point(point=(18.515802, 73.846754), dist=700)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_route(G, route, bbox = bbox, route_linewidth=6, node_size=0, bgcolor=bgcolor,dpi = 300)

routes = ox.k_shortest_paths(G, origin_node, destination_node, k=3, weight='length')
bbox = ox.utils_geo.bbox_from_point(point=(18.515802, 73.846754), dist=700)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_routes(G, list(routes), bbox = bbox, route_colors=['r','b','g'], route_linewidth=2, node_size=0, bgcolor=bgcolor,dpi = 300)
```

The above code runs fine. However the background is black and very basic. I want the background to be interactive colored map, something like folium:

I tried this for the shortest path using ox.plot_route_folium, and it worked fine

```
   ox.plot_route_folium(G, route, popup_attribute='length')
```

For the shortest 3 paths "routes", I tried the below and it gave me the below error:

```
ox.plot_route_folium(G, routes, popup_attribute='length')



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-2d9737bbef6b> in <module>
----> 1 ox.plot_route_folium(G, routes, popup_attribute='length')
      2 
      3 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/folium.py in plot_route_folium(G, route, route_map, popup_attribute, tiles, zoom, fit_bounds, **kwargs)
     92     """
     93     # create gdf of the route edges in order
---> 94     node_pairs = zip(route[:-1], route[1:])
     95     uvk = ((u, v, min(G[u][v], key=lambda k: G[u][v][k]["length"])) for u, v in node_pairs)
     96     gdf_edges = utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G.subgraph(route), nodes=False).loc[uvk]

TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Edit:  I've already tried this converting generator to list: routes=list(routes). However, it gives empty list: [] after conversion.

Any advice, please?
Thanks,

Comment: Because `routes` is a generator, that's why when you convert it to a `list` in the call to `plot_graph_routes` it works.

Comment: Hello, I've already tried this converting generator to list: routes=list(routes). However, it gives empty list: [] after conversion.

Comment: You can only access a generator once. The second time it will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass it routes (plural), as a generator of lists. You must pass it a single list representing a single route, as stated in its [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.folium.plot_route_folium).

Comment: Hello gboeing..yes.. I'm passing it routes (plural), as I want to plot the 3 routes simultaneously on the same map. Any idea for combining the 3 routes together on a interactive map, please?